# Two independent scripts getting mixed up and giving unexpected output

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to serve 2 quizzes on the same page, however when I click the button **Get Score**, the first one doesn't work.  I have got these two Javascripts in the head:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var q1numQues = 5;
    var q1numChoi = 4;

    var q1answers = new Array(5);
    q1answers[0] = "11";
    q1answers[1] = "3";
    q1answers[2] = "8";
    q1answers[3] = "15";
    q1answers[4] = "4";

    function getQuiz1Score(form) {
        var score = 0;
        var currElt;
        var currSelection;

        for (i = 0; i < q1numQues; i++) {
            currElt = i * q1numChoi;
            for (j = 0; j < q1numChoi; j++) {
                currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
                if (currSelection.checked) {
                    if (currSelection.value == q1answers[i]) {
                        score++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        score = Math.round(score / q1numQues * 100);
        form.percentage.value = score + "%";

        var correctAnswers = "";
        for (i = 1; i <= q1numQues; i++) {
            correctAnswers += i + ". " + q1answers[i - 1] + "\r\n";
        }
        form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;
        break;

    }
</script>


<script language="JavaScript">
    var q2numQues = 4;
    var q2numChoi = 3;

    var q2answers = new Array(4);
    q2answers[0] = "UK";
    q2answers[1] = "USA";
    q2answers[2] = "Mexico";
    q2answers[3] = "Canada";

    function getQuiz2Score(form) {
        var score = 0;
        var currElt;
        var currSelection;

        for (i = 0; i < q2numQues; i++) {
            currElt = i * q2numChoi;
            for (j = 0; j < q2numChoi; j++) {
                currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
                if (currSelection.checked) {
                    if (currSelection.value == q2answers[i]) {
                        score++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        score = Math.round(score / q2numQues * 100);
        form.percentage.value = score + "%";

        var correctAnswers = "";
        for (i = 1; i <= q2numQues; i++) {
            correctAnswers += i + ". " + q2answers[i - 1] + "\r\n";
        }
        form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;

    }
</script>
```

And these are my quizzes:

```
   <div class="container" id="pill">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mathquiz">Maths Quiz</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#geographyquiz">Geography Quiz</a></li>


            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="mathquiz" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img src="images/math.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Our Values Banner">
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <h4 align="center">Maths Quiz - Please click Get Score after completing to get your score</h4>

                    <form name="quiz" align="center"> <b>
1. What is 4+7?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="5">5<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="10">10<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="11">11<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="20">20<br>


2. What is 5-2?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">0<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="5">5<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="3">3<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="8">8<br>


3. What is 4*2?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="33">33<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="20">20<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="8">8<br>


4. What is 3+12?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="15">15<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="4">4<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="78">78<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="1">1<br>


5. What is 8/2?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="4">4<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="7">7<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="9">9<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="8">8<br>


<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getQuiz1Score(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage"><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea> </b>
                    </form>
                </div>


                <div id="geographyquiz" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="image-container">
                        <img src="images/geography.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Geography Quiz">
                    </div>

                    <h4 align="center">Geography Quiz</h4>


                    <form name="quiz" align="center"> <b>
Identify the country the flag belongs to! <br><br>
1. <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/britishflag.png" class="img-responsive" alt="British Flag">
                </div><br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="UK">UK<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="Germany">Germany<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="Italy">Italy<br><br>


2. <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/usaflag.png" class="img-responsive" alt="USA Flag">
                </div><br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="Ireland">Ireland<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="Belgium">Belgium<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="USA">USA<br><br>


3. <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/mexicoflag.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Mexican Flag">
                </div><br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Brazil">Brazil<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Mexico">Mexico<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Chile">Chile<br><br>


4. <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/canadaflag.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Canadian Flag">
                </div><br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="Japan">Japan<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="Portugal">Portugal<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="Canada">Canada<br>


<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getQuiz2Score(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage"><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea> </b>
                    </form>


                </div>
```

Please help me to make the Get Score buttons work.

Comment: At the moment, you are just duplicating the first script, with the same variable names etc. You need to rename your variables used in the second block to something different. Just because they are two different scripts, doesn't mean they have different scope. Your functions, var declarations are in the same scope.

Comment: Completely irrelevant but I hope that your students aren't super familiar with JavaScript or using Developer Tools within a browser :)

Comment: @RionWilliams I'm a student!

Comment: I figured (as quizzes are a good learning tool); Just was imagining a teacher building a test and not realizing that a student could just look at the source and see the answers).

Comment: @user3902129 Read the beginning of my answer. I highly suspect that the `<--` you start your script off with is causing the first script to not run.

Comment: @8protons I removed it, no luck.

Comment: @RionWilliams I tried your answer, however still no out for the first quiz :(

Comment: @user3902129 You have a combination of issues. Commenting out the code was only one of them :P You need to refactor your code so everything isn't global; or use different global variable names.

Comment: @user3902129 update your code with out suggestions. If it _still_ doesn't work, we'll go from there. But we need to have some assurance that you're effectively and properly trying our suggestions.

Comment: The snippet provided in [my response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36895953/557445) appears to work just as expected. I'd recommend removing the comment snippets like `<--` and `-->` as per [8proton's recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36896093/557445) and your code should work.

Comment: @8protons I've updated the code

Comment: @RionWilliams I've updated the code

Comment: Try removing the `break;` statement at the bottom of your `getQuiz1Score()` function. You can [see the fixed code here](http://jsbin.com/qorocu/edit?html,output).

Comment: @RionWilliams Don't know how the break; got there lol but OMG it's working!!!

Comment: These things happen. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Note: The following was relevant before the OP made edits to implement the changes suggested below. The fix for the OP came down to a superfluous `break` as pointed out in [Rion Williams's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36895953/5137782).**

The first script starts with

```
 <script language="JavaScript">
<!--

var numQues = 5;
var numChoi = 4;
```

What is that `<!--` doing there? You delimit this comment later in the script but you comment out the delimeter by writing `// -->`.

Anyways, your second script starts with

```
<script language="JavaScript">

var numQues = 4;
var numChoi = 3;
```

Something you need to understand is that you're declaring these variables globally; at any given point in time, `numQuest` in script A is the exact same as `numQuest` in script B (and vice versa) . Due to the nature of declaring variables globally in JavaScript, when you write

```
var numQuest = 5;
```

you're effectively writing

```
window.numQuest = 5;
```

which sets the variable `numQuest` as defined and accessible across the entire Browser Object Model (BOM). [Read this resource](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window.asp) on `window` and BOM.

You need to either rename your variables or scope the variables like so:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    (function() {
        var numQues = 5;
        var numChoi = 4;
        ... rest of code ...
     })();
</script>
```

I would suggest that you thoroughly read this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8348725/5137782

Answer (score 1):

**Scoping and Function Overwriting Issues**

Currently the names of your functions are the same `getScore(name)` so the second declaration is actually overwriting the first and your variables are doing the same.

Consider changing each of them to `getQ1Score()` and `getQ2Score()` respectively along with where they are called and appending `q1` and `q2` to your variables and their declarations as well :

```
// Quiz 1 variables
var q1numQues = 5;
var q1numChoi = 4;
var q1answers = ["11", "3", "8", "15", "4"];
// Quiz 1 score function
function getQ1Score(form) { 
    /* Omitted for brevity (but ensure you update your variable names too) */
}
```

along with :

```
<!-- This will explicitly call your Q1 score calculation -->
<input type="button" value="Get score" onclick="getQ1Score(this.form)">
```

**These are the `break;`s**

Additionally, you have a straggling `break;` statement at then of your `getQuiz1Score()`, which would cause things to freak out :

```
// Remove this to get things up and running
break;
```

**Consider Refactoring A Bit**

Overall, you may want to consider some of the points addressed in [8proton's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36896093/557445) regarding scoping your functions so you wouldn't have to worry about renaming everything (especially if you intend to add some additional quizzes in the future).

**Example Output and Snippet With Updated Changes**

[image]

```js
// Quiz 1 variables
var q1numQues = 5;
var q1numChoi = 4;
var q1answers = ["11", "3", "8", "15", "4"];
// Quiz 1 score function
function getQ1Score(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;

  for (i = 0; i < q1numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i * q1numChoi;
    for (j = 0; j < q1numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == answers[i]) {
          score++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  score = Math.round(score / q1numQues * 100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";

  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= q1numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + q1answers[i - 1] + "\r\n";
  }
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;

}

// -->


// Quiz 2 variables
var q2numQues = 4;
var q2numChoi = 3;
var q2answers = ["UK", "USA", "Mexico", "Canada"];
// Quiz 2 score function
function getQ2Score(form) {
  var score = 0;
  var currElt;
  var currSelection;

  for (i = 0; i < q2numQues; i++) {
    currElt = i * q2numChoi;
    for (j = 0; j < q2numChoi; j++) {
      currSelection = form.elements[currElt + j];
      if (currSelection.checked) {
        if (currSelection.value == q2answers[i]) {
          score++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  score = Math.round(score / q2numQues * 100);
  form.percentage.value = score + "%";

  var correctAnswers = "";
  for (i = 1; i <= q2numQues; i++) {
    correctAnswers += i + ". " + q2answers[i - 1] + "\r\n";
  }
  form.solutions.value = correctAnswers;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="mathquiz" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="images/math.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Our Values Banner">
      </div>
      <br>
      <h4 align="center">Maths Quiz - Please click Get Score after completing to get your score</h4>

      <form name="quiz1" align="center"> <b>
1. What is 4+7?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="5">5<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="10">10<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="11">11<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="20">20<br>


2. What is 5-2?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="0">0<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="5">5<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="3">3<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="8">8<br>


3. What is 4*2?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="33">33<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="20">20<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="1">1<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="8">8<br>


4. What is 3+12?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="15">15<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="4">4<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="78">78<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="1">1<br>


5. What is 8/2?<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="4">4<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="7">7<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="9">9<br>
<input type="radio" name="q5" value="8">8<br>


<input type="button" value="Get score" onclick="getQ1Score(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage"><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea> </b>
      </form>
    </div>


    <div id="geographyquiz" class="tab-pane fade">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img src="images/geography.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Geography Quiz">
      </div>

      <h4 align="center">Geography Quiz</h4>


      <form name="quiz2" align="center"> <b>
Identify the country the flag belongs to! <br><br>
1. <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/britishflag.png" class="img-responsive" alt="British Flag">
                </div><br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="UK">UK<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="Germany">Germany<br>
<input type="radio" name="q1" value="Italy">Italy<br><br>


2. <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/usaflag.png" class="img-responsive"    alt="USA Flag">
                </div><br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="Ireland">Ireland<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="Belgium">Belgium<br>
<input type="radio" name="q2" value="USA">USA<br><br>


3. <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/mexicoflag.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Mexican Flag">
                </div><br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Brazil">Brazil<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Mexico">Mexico<br>
<input type="radio" name="q3" value="Chile">Chile<br><br>


4. <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="images/canadaflag.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Canadian Flag">
                </div><br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="Japan">Japan<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="Portugal">Portugal<br>
<input type="radio" name="q4" value="Canada">Canada<br>


<input type="button" value="Get score" onClick="getQ2Score(this.form)">
<input type="reset" value="Clear">
Score = <input type=text size=15 name="percentage"><br>
Correct answers:<br>
<textarea name="solutions" wrap="virtual" rows="4" cols="40"></textarea>     </b>
      </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since your comment on the question was, "Try removing the `break;` statement at the bottom of your getQuiz1Score() function." and it fixed it for the OP, would you mind putting that comment in your answer for others? My answer directs readers to yours.

Comment: Done. I organized things a bit and referenced your post as well as it addresses some important points on scoping and some improvements that OP (and others) may want to consider.

Comment: @RionWilliams Thanks, Rion, I appreciate that. Btw, how did you embed that animation into your answer? It looks so nice; haven't seen that on SO  before.

Comment: I use [RecordIt](http://recordit.co/) to record me doing something and then I save it as a `.gif` and upload it as you would any other image :)