# link between 2 js files

Tags: javascript, html

I try to 'transfer' a variable from one js file to another.

I already tried to use import/export however it didn't work.

test1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=<device-width>, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h1 class="sentence">hey guys</h1>
    </div>
    <script src="test1.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test1.js

```
let greeting=document.querySelector('.sentence').innerHTML;
console.log(greeting);
```

test2.js

```
$.getScript('test1.js',function(){
    console.log(greeting);
})
```

the error messages i get are:
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///Users/michalislazaris/Desktop/test.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).
and:
Module source URI is not allowed in this document: “file:///Users/michalislazaris/Desktop/test.js”.

Comment: Because you're running them on your local file system. They should be fine on a website/web server.

Comment: Your error message talks about test.js but you've said your files are test**1**.js and test**2**.js, so does test.js even exist?

Comment: Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348401/javascript-two-separate-scripts-share-variables and many others. Maybe check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Two separate scripts - share variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348401/javascript-two-separate-scripts-share-variables)

Comment: @MattEllen i just changed test.js to test1.js in stackoverflow in order to make it clear. The real file is named test.js

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error messages generated you're running your application locally. This results in the blocked [CROSS-Origin Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) since both pages aren't located on the same "server".

In order to solve this, you have to run your application on a development server and there are tons of options to pick from! My personal favorite is [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), which is pretty straight forward (minimal config) to use.

Once your app is running on a server the error must disappear.

Comment: ty <3 i will try it