# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function error

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a small code with FullCalendar library displaying 2 calendars. One on the first tab, one on the 2nd tab. Both calendars show up, however, the one that is invisible when the page loads is not showing up properly.

[image]

Full code: https://codepen.io/MadBoyEvo/pen/rNxQQYP

So I thought I would do a refresh or quickly change the view from current to new one and back to current on a tab switch but whatever  I do it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var tabs = tabbis.init({
        tabGroup: "[data-tabs]",
        paneGroup: "[data-panes]",
        tabActive: "active",
        paneActive: "active",
        callback: function (tab, pane) {
            // console.log("TAB id:" + tab.id);
            // console.log(pane.id);
            // console.log(tableid);
            // this makes sure to refresh tables on tab change to make sure they have buttons and everything
            // it's a bit heavy as it touches all tables, may require some improvements in future to consider
            // which tab has which table
            try {
                var tableid = document.getElementById(tab.id + "-Content").querySelector('table[id^="DT-"]').id;
                $("#" + tableid).DataTable().columns.adjust().responsive.recalc();
            } catch (e) {
                console.log('No datatables available.');
            }
            
            // this code here doesn't work
            var view = $('#Calendar-on26xq0w').fullCalendar('getView');
            alert("The view's title is " + view.title);
        }
    });

    // in theory should take care of removing local storage for tabbis
    // some errors occurs if the local storage is not cleaned after a while
    window.addEventListener("unload", tabbis.remove, false);
</script><!-- JS Elastic Tabbis END -->
```

The error shows up: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function`

I tried moving calendar.js script from top to bottom, to before or after the script code that fails but nothing is helping.

I am a bit of JS noob so it's a bit unclear to me why it doesn't work. I used similar approach for DataTables (the Try/catch) and it works fine (if there is DataTable loaded)

Edit:

I've tried searching for calendar id - and I can find it, yet the same error is visible on that 3rd line.

```
var calendarid = document.getElementById(tab.id + "-Content").querySelector('div[id^="Calendar-"]').id;
alert("The calendarid " + calendarid);
var view = $('#' + calendarid).fullCalendar('getView');
alert("The view's title is " + view.title);
```

Comment: If you're using fullcalendar v5 as per your tag, then `$('#Calendar-on26xq0w').fullCalendar` will never work - that's the syntax from fullCalendar v3 (back when it was a jQuery plugin, hence the jQuery-style selector to initialise the object). If you want to call a method in v4 or v5 then you need a reference to the object you created when initialising the calendar, and then to get the current view you can simply write `calendar.view` (it's a property not a function) - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view . (There's no such function as `getView` in v5 either.)

Comment: @ADyson oh, but how do I get "calendar"?                             var calendar = document.getElementById(tab.id + "-Content").querySelectorAll('div[id^="Calendar-"]'); calendar.view won't work. In other words how do i reference existing calendar that I find using querySelectorAll.

Comment: No, calendar isn't an DOM element (so you can't select it with something like querySelectorAll), it's a variable your code created. e.g. when you initialise the calendar originally you have to write something like `var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar...`. It's that `calendar` object that you need a reference to.

Comment: That I am aware, but each of my calendars is always defined as` var calendar` in the code. I was thinking that I can find it by QuerySelector and somehow reference it later on by it's ID. It doesn't work that way? Keep in mind that I am trying to access this calendar on tab switch from different script, so I don't see those defined variables. How would I go and select proper calendar

Comment: @ADyson found it! Thank you!

Comment: "I was thinking that I can find it by QuerySelector and somehow reference it later on by it's ID. It doesn't work that way?"...no, querySelector is for selecting DOM elements (i.e. the objects which represent the pieces of HTML on your page), it has nothing to do with other variables within JavaScript. You perhaps need a data structure in which to keep these calendar references e.g. an array, or an object with named properties, with a scope which is sufficiently accessible. (I see from your profile you've got a lot of rep from C#/powershell, so hopefully those concepts are familiar to you.)

Comment: Ye, i figured it out. `var calendar1 = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendar.id); calendar1.view;` works based on the DOM element from query selector. I was just confused that you need to use `new` which i assumed would destroy that object. Or at least i think it works that way - maybe I'm just creating new object and it shows me defaults :-)

Comment: Unfortunately I was wrong. It does destroy my object creating new one in it's place it seems. So still need to find a way to reference existing calendar without destroying it. I am not sure how to do that, unfortunately. I do understand C#/PowerShell concepts not sure how I can pass that stuff between different scripts. I solved similar issue with DataTables by simply referencing existing table via query selector and once I had that I was able to manipulate it. Thought the same is possible for FullCalendar.

Comment: Yes, `new` does create a new object, it's a constructor again just like C#. And, more importantly `var` creates a new variable. But if you had another variable of the same name elsewhere, it would only destroy the old variable if they were both in the _same scope_ (same concept as C#, although JavaScript's actual rules about scope are somewhat different).

Comment: _"I solved similar issue with DataTables by simply referencing existing table via query selector"_ ...yes but that's because you're referencing a DOM element, which is always available. You can't do that with a plain variable.

Comment: Like I said, if you want to keep a list of the different calendars you've declared, then add them to an array or object structure.

Comment: Can't I reference the DOM element, find it's ID, and then reference that object? I don't understand the difference of behavior between manipulating DataTable and FullCalendar. I would assume it's the same concept. I guess I can go to PowerShell and fix it in PowerShell (since I generate it via PowerShell using https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSWriteHTML so if I am having to keep array of sorts I may as well track it with PowerShell and hardcode it in the callback function.

Comment: No you can't. You passed the DOM element id into fullCalendar's constructor. fullCalendar uses that to draw the calendar on screen. Then, fullCalendar's constructor returns the fullCalendar object which you need for interacting with the calendar. The only link then between the DOM element and that object is held internally within fullCalendar. The object holds a reference to the DOM element, not the other way round.

Comment: I don't know DataTables very well, but as far as I know it's a jQuery plugin. jQuery works by creating a jQuery object which is linked to a DOM element. So there you have the opposite effect where the DOM element provides you a link to the object. It's a different scenario to the way fullCalendar works.

Comment: I understand now. I guess I need to read on the equivalent of hashtables in Javascript, store key DOM ID, calendar object and call that in callback function - where I would find object by searching DOM ID in the hashtable.

Comment: You could certainly do that. Working with data objects in JS is very simple, at the most basic level it's just a collection of name/value pairs - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: One thing I am missing is how to make that variable global? I defined object at the top in separate <script>var myObject = { ... }</script> but it doesn't work in another <script></scriptblock> which is understandable. I saw window variable but that seems like overkill. I see someone mentioned this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348401/javascript-two-separate-scripts-share-variables but is it best way?

Comment: A variable declared in one script block A should be visible in script block B, as long as B appears later than A in the HTML.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you so much. Do you know if it's possible rerender calendar in diff way? Currently I am doing it by changing view to same view it was which works on tab switch                       `function testCalendar(calendar) {
    var id = calendar.id;
    console.log(myCar[id].view);
    var tempView = myCar[id].view.type
    //myCar[id].changeView('dayGridWeek');
    myCar[id].changeView(tempView);
    //myCar[id].render();
}`

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-render should be sufficient to render / re-render the calendar. You seem to have got that command, but have commented it out. Was there some problem with it?

Comment: I've posted my answer with full description what I did and how it solved my issue. thank you again, it seems to work correctly for my needs.

Comment: @ADyson yes, using render would throw an error. Most likely due to it being rendered already. But it seems just resetting view to the same view I have works as expected so solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @ADyson from comments I was able to understand my issues:

- FullCalendar V5 doesn't have the method I was trying to use

> If you're using fullcalendar v5 as per your tag, then
> $('#Calendar-on26xq0w').fullCalendar will never work - that's the
> syntax from fullCalendar v3 (back when it was a jQuery plugin, hence
> the jQuery-style selector to initialise the object). If you want to
> call a method in v4 or v5 then you need a reference to the object you
> created when initialising the calendar, and then to get the current
> view you can simply write calendar.view (it's a property not a
> function) - see fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view . (There's no such
> function as getView in v5 either.)

- I can't use query DOM Object and pass it somehow to FullCalendar as I was trying to do
- What I actually have to do is create object https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and store relevant JS objects.

At the very top defined empty object

```html
<!-- JS FullCalendar Basic START -->
<script type="text/javascript">var calendarTracker = {

    };
</script><!-- JS FullCalendar Basic END -->
<!-- CSS FullCalendar Basic START -->
```

Next for each calendar that I created

```html
<script>document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('Calendar-c43nxqpi');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,
            {
                "headerToolbar": {
                    "left": "prev,next,today",
                    "right": "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth",
                    "center": "title"
                },
                "initialView": "listWeek",
                "initialDate": "2020-07-20",
                "nowIndicator": true,
                "navLinks": true,
                "businessHours": false,
                "editable": false,
                "events": [
                    {
                        "title": "Active Directory Meeting",
                        "description": "We will talk about stuff",
                        "start": "2020-07-20T11:43:35"
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Lunch",
                        "description": "Very long lunch",
                        "start": "2020-07-22T08:43:35",
                        "end": "2020-07-23T11:43:35"
                    }
                ],
                "dayMaxEventRows": true,
                "weekNumbers": true,
                "weekNumberCalculation": "ISO",
                "selectable": true,
                "selectMirror": true,
                "buttonIcons": false,
                "views": {
                    "listWeek": {
                        "buttonText": "list week"
                    },
                    "listMonth": {
                        "buttonText": "list month"
                    },
                    "listDay": {
                        "buttonText": "list day"
                    }
                },
                eventRender: function (info) {
                    var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                        title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                        placement: 'top',
                        trigger: 'hover',
                        container: 'body'
                    });
                }
            }
        );
        calendar.render();
        calendarTracker['Calendar-c43nxqpi'] = calendar;
    }); 
</script>
```

I've stored this calendar object with key based on it's html id.

```
calendarTracker['Calendar-c43nxqpi'] = calendar;
```

Finally on tab switch

```
<script type="text/javascript">var tabs = tabbis.init({
    tabGroup: "[data-tabs]",
    paneGroup: "[data-panes]",
    tabActive: "active",
    paneActive: "active",
    callback: function (tab, pane) {
        // We need to make same thing for calendar
        function redrawCalendar(calendar) {
            //console.log(calendarTracker[calendar.id].view);
            calendarTracker[calendar.id].changeView(calendarTracker[calendar.id].view.type);
            console.log('Redrawing view for' + calendar.id)
        }

        try {
            var calendar = document.getElementById(tab.id + "-Content").querySelectorAll('div[id^="Calendar-"]');
            calendar.forEach(redrawCalendar)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('No calendars available.');
        }
    }
});

// in theory should take care of removing local storage for tabbis
// some errors occurs if the local storage is not cleaned after a while
window.addEventListener("unload", tabbis.remove, false);
</script>
```

I'm basically finding all calendars on the given tab using `querySelectorAll` and then for each calendar on the tab I'm running redrawCalendar function which based on the HTML DOM ID finds the correct calendar object, and resets its view making sure the visual part is up and running again.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **calendar2** on the fly when the **user** tries to switch to the next tab. Listen for the `change event` on the `tab` and initialize the second **calendar** based on the `calendarID`.

```
 var calendarid = document.getElementById(tab.id + "-Content").querySelector('div[id^="Calendar-"]').id;
                    // alert("The calendarid " + calendarid);
                  if(calendarid == 'Calendar-3fso0g65') {
                    loadCalendarFirst(calendarid);
                  } else {
                    loadCalendarSecond(calendarid);
                  }
```

I added the following two methods to call when needed

```
<script>
        function loadCalendarFirst(claendarID) {
          var calendarEl = document.getElementById(claendarID);
                    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,
                        {
                            "headerToolbar": {
                                "left": "prev,next,today",
                                "right": "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth",
                                "center": "title"
                            },
                            "initialView": "listWeek",
                            "initialDate": "2020-07-19",
                            "nowIndicator": true,
                            "navLinks": true,
                            "businessHours": false,
                            "editable": false,
                            "events": [
                                {
                                    "title": "Active Directory Meeting",
                                    "description": "We will talk about stuff",
                                    "start": "2020-07-19T10:07:02"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "Lunch",
                                    "description": "Very long lunch",
                                    "start": "2020-07-21T07:07:02",
                                    "end": "2020-07-22T10:07:02"
                                }
                            ],
                            "dayMaxEventRows": true,
                            "weekNumbers": true,
                            "weekNumberCalculation": "ISO",
                            "selectable": true,
                            "selectMirror": true,
                            "buttonIcons": false,
                            "views": {
                                "listWeek": {
                                    "buttonText": "list week"
                                },
                                "listMonth": {
                                    "buttonText": "list month"
                                },
                                "listDay": {
                                    "buttonText": "list day"
                                }
                            },
                            eventRender: function (info) {
                                var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                                    title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                                    placement: 'top',
                                    trigger: 'hover',
                                    container: 'body'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    calendar.render();
        }
        
        function loadCalendarSecond(calendarID) {
                    var calendarEl = document.getElementById(calendarID);
                    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl,
                        {
                            "headerToolbar": {
                                "left": "prev,next,today",
                                "right": "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth",
                                "center": "title"
                            },
                            "initialDate": "2020-07-19",
                            "nowIndicator": true,
                            "navLinks": true,
                            "businessHours": false,
                            "editable": false,
                            "events": [
                                {
                                    "title": "Active Directory Meeting",
                                    "description": "We will talk about stuff",
                                    "start": "2020-07-19T10:07:02"
                                },
                                {
                                    "title": "Lunch",
                                    "description": "Very long lunch",
                                    "start": "2020-07-21T07:07:02",
                                    "end": "2020-07-22T10:07:02"
                                }
                            ],
                            "dayMaxEventRows": true,
                            "weekNumbers": true,
                            "weekNumberCalculation": "ISO",
                            "selectable": true,
                            "selectMirror": true,
                            "buttonIcons": false,
                            "views": {
                                "listWeek": {
                                    "buttonText": "list week"
                                },
                                "listMonth": {
                                    "buttonText": "list month"
                                },
                                "listDay": {
                                    "buttonText": "list day"
                                }
                            },
                            eventRender: function (info) {
                                var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
                                    title: info.event.extendedProps.description,
                                    placement: 'top',
                                    trigger: 'hover',
                                    container: 'body'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    calendar.render();
        }
        
        loadCalendarFirst('Calendar-3fso0g65');
      </script>
```

Here's the [Updated Plunker](https://codepen.io/basheerahmed/pen/PoZxxaj?editors=1001)

Comment: This would mean I would need to generate code differently while doing it with tabs and without tabs. Isn't there a way to solve it in my way? It seems I just have to somehow solve issue of finding my calendar which for some reason doesn't work.

Comment: @MadBoy With the tabs you don't need to change anything except the lines where `hide/show` functions are called

Comment: @MadBoy Edit the plunker and add the `tabs` stuffs, I will make it work with that as well.

Comment: Can you try to apply what you are showing to my "tabs". Those are a bit different.

Comment: @MadBoy update the plunker and add those `tabs` so I can make the necessary changes

Comment: Updated. For some reason I pasted wrong codepen ‍♂️

Comment: Thank you. I'll test it out locally if I can automate things around it. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I've been working on your code and it works, however it gets complicated while trying to manage multiple calendars and multiple tabs. While I have no problem to generate random function names in the body and load all calendars (it's hard to say which tab will be first on user open), but then it would also mean I need to track id's and calendar function names with those ids to properly show calendar on given tab. Do you see an easier, more "automated" way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218176/discussion-between-basheer-kharoti-and-madboy).

Answer (score -1):

The error indicates that the element you try to run the `fullCalendar()` function on is not available. This means that the HTML element with the ID `Calendar-on26xq0w` can't be found on the document.

Comment: Right, the thing is I can find the said calendar ID if I use query selector (updated question with Edit showing it)